How to install parabolic in Ubuntu 24.04 without snap or flatpak?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 with a laptop with limited storage in its internal drive, and to save space, I want to avoid snaps and flatpaks.
I want to install the Parabolic YouTube downloader, which is a frontend of yt-dlp. How to install it in 24.04 without snap or flatpak?

You can use the Xtradeb PPA, which also hosts Chromium.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xtradeb/apps -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install parabolic

